# stopping a rotation notification from propagating to the child views

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm using device orientation notification in order to know if the device has been rotated so that i can perform a selector. here is the code i'm using:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
        !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"landscape" sender:self];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&
             isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}
```

however, when i navigate to the other child views and rotate the device, the selector is performed although the above code are in a class that is independent from the classes that the other views have. so how can i stop that? i tried:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

and it also didn't work. my app actually pop into another view in landscape mode when the device is rotated. so in the child views, the landscape view appears in i rotate the device. how can i fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

To remove all notifications

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your parent view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods {
    return NO;
}
```

From the docs:

> This method is called to determine whether to automatically forward
>   rotation-related containment callbacks to child view controllers.
>
> The default implementation returns `YES`. Subclasses of the
>   UIViewController class that implement containment logic may override
>   this method to control how these methods are forwarded. If you
>   override this method and return `NO`, you are responsible for forwarding
>   the following methods to child view controllers at the appropriate
>   times:
>
> `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`
>   `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`
>   `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`